# Correct pose topic could not be subscribed via rviz

Tags: rviz, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have defined a pose topic as below:

```
    pose_pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Pose>("new_pose", 50);
```

But then, after assigning all related fields for position and orientation and also publishing it, I cannot opt for the topic of "/new_pose" under pose message. Instead, it offers me a topic which I never define it (goal(geometry_msgs/PoseStamped)). There is also a warning there saying that "no messages received". However, if I issue "rostopic echo -c /new_pose", there are changing values of position and orientation.

What is the possible culprit for this? I'm on ROS Electric anyway..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11751/correct-pose-topic-could-not-be-subscribed-via-rviz/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try publishing a `geometry_msgs/PoseStamped` message, instead of a `geometry_msgs/Pose` message.  `rviz` needs the frame ID and time (that's what's in the "stamp") to be able to transform and display data.

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-11-01**:
oo, I've just got to invoke for the member function..thanks a lot..

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-11-01**:
How do I define the id, like in laser scanner we can do "scan.header.frame_id = "laser_frame";", when I try pose., it's not there header as a member function..